# (Psychtoolbox help ) Presenting stimuli based on keyboard response?

Tags: psychtoolbox

I want to present stimuli 1 on the screen and  if a specific response 1 is made, stimuli 2 is presented and then the user needs to press a specific key (response 2) and when they do they are presented with stimuli 3. I'm able to workout how to present stimuli 2 based on the response 1 while stimuli 1 is presented. but not able to move to stimuli 3. I'm guessing its because i'm storing it as 'response', once it has value, it doesn't get updated again?. how to fix this? thanks in advance

```
%presenting text 1
Screen('DrawText',window,'stimuli1',xcen,ycen);
Screen('Flip',window)

%intiating keyboard
[keyIsDown, RTkeyCode] = KbWait;
r=find(RTkeyCode);%this should be the code for the key pressed
response=KbName(r);%Figure out what key strong text

Screen('TextSize',window,60)
       Screen('DrawText',window,'question',xcen,ycen);
       Screen('Flip',window)
       WaitSecs(2)
       if response=='b'
           Screen('DrawText',window,'stmuli2',xcen,ycen)
           Screen('Flip',window)
       end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a few solutions you can try.

1. Keep using `KbWait(-1); WaitSecs(2);` to wait for keypress and then a few additional seconds when the key should be lifted
2. Use a few commands that can help get rid of stored responses such as `KbEventFlush(deviceIndex);`
3. Something perfect to look at for additional help is PsychToolboxes `KbQueueDemo.m` script. Type `open KbQueueDemo.m` into Matlab terminal to open it up and examine it. Run it so you know what's going on. I think this will help you a lot